# How to delete chat messages from XMPP server in android or ios?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, xmppframework

Now i am doing chat application. I am using XMPP for chat. 
I am able to do chat. Now I want to delete chat message in my chat message list like a whats app. 
That message will delete also in server.How can I delete the particluar chat message from server.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Mobile libraries for iOS: XMPPFramework,
Mobile libraries for Android: Smack,
Server: ejabberd OR Openfire

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that messages are not stored separately on your server.
Only complete conversations are stored. 
That being said, you would have to delete the whole conversation for one message.

The only way to achieve what you want, is to create separate conversations for each message.

There is an experimental XMPP-Extension, but it is not yet implemented http://legastero.github.io/customxeps/extensions/message-delete.html